# css-portrait view on iPad not working

Tags: css

I have included a stylesheet in my html to display the page in a different way on my iPad.
Here is what I did:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="/themes/pmz/css/portrait.css" />
```

Now I just want to make the background color black if the user turns his iPad in portrait.
I use the following css-statement:

```
/*Stylesheet for the ipad wenn in portrait position*/
 body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Now this works on my desktop machine in Firefox if I make the width smaller than the height. Unfortunately, Safari doesn't make the background black, neither on my desktop machine nor on the iPad.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it on my iPod Touch (iOS 5) and it works well for me. Maybe the path to your CSS file is wrong?

Comment: Ah, I made a similar mistake with an invalid path. Thanks much for helping and testing Snoopy.